# file edit- commandline unix

Tags: linux, file, unix, sed

I want to edit a file from the command line, because opening it in vim or other editors takes forever (a large file). I want to add a string ('chr') to the beginning of every line that is not commented out with a #. The command I am using is this:

```
cat '/home/me/37.vcf' | sed s/^/chr/>'sp.vcf'
```

But it adds a chr to the beginning of EVERY line and a > to the END of every line. I don't want either of those things to occur.
Can anyone offer any suggestions to improve my results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To apply the substitution to only the lines that don't start with a `#`:

```
sed '/^[^#]/s/^/chr/' file > output
```

Note: the command `cat` is for concatenating files, it is useless here.

Comment: It won't add `chr` on blank lines. Not sure if OP wants it that way or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can syntax error in your sed command. Use this syntactically correct sed command:

```
sed -E 's/^([^#]|$)/chr/' /home/me/37.vcf > sp.vcf
```

OR on Linux:

```
sed -r 's/^([^#]|$)/chr/' /home/me/37.vcf > sp.vcf
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^\s*#/!s/^/chr/' file > new_file
```